# Changing font in Twitter feed embedded on Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, twitter

Apologies if I have missed the simple answer to what would seem an embarrassingly simple question! [There is an old question here but the answer seems to involve digging into javascript, and people aren't falling over themselves to respond to this same query on Wordpress.se]

OK: I have just added a Twitter timeline to the footer of my Wordpress site, https://www.logicmatters.net, using the Twitter-provided html code

`<a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="auto" data-height="300" data-chrome="nofooter noheader noborders transparent" href="https://twitter.com/PeterSmith?ref_src=XXXXXX">Tweets by PeterSmith</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8" ></script>`

As you will see, the tweets are displayed with black font colour. *Is it possible to change this in a **simple** way*? Can I either to add to this html, or add a CSS snippet [e.g. using the governing Astra theme's CSS snippets panel] which will control at least the tweet's font colour (both for the tweet text and the tweet header)?

Ideally I'd like to control the font selection too.